# What is the expression for the area enclosed by this shape? i.e., is there a closed form for this integral?

Tags: definite-integrals, area

[Here is the graph of the shape I'm interested in](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2khvolbxkh). It's essentially an ellipse, but instead of the distances to the focal points summing to one, they multiply to one.

It has the equation $y^2 = -x^2 - c^2 + \sqrt{4x^2c^2 + 1}$, and I'd like to find the area under it. Just for the simple case where c < 0 (that is the shape does not expand into two regions), the X coordinate where the shape intersects the X axis is given by $\sqrt{1 + c^2}$ (solving the above equation for $y = 0$).

Since the shape is symmetrical over both the X and Y axes, it can be simplified to four times the area of one of the sections (in this case, quadrant 1). That results in the integral:

$\text{Area} = 4\int^\sqrt{1+c^2}_0 \sqrt{-x^2 - c^2+\sqrt{4x^2c^2 + 1}}dx$

Is there possibly a closed form for this? Or (like most weird integrals) does it have no closed form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your curve is a [Cassini oval](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CassiniOvals.html).  If it is, the area , in general, cannot be found with elementary functions but only with elliptic integrals ( see also [here](https://archive.lib.msu.edu/crcmath/math/math/c/c084.htm)).

Comment: Well that's a shame. Nice to know for sure though. Thank you!